# embedded media on iframe zooms in windows.print()

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing, embed, powerbi-embedded

I have an embedded media on my website which looks like this on code. I've used the embed-responsive component of bootstrap to auto-resize the media depending on the size of the screen. It looks great and works well on the browser but then when I use `window.print()` the media gets zoomed in and parts of it gets cut off.

```
<div id="powerbi-include" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe id="iframePrint" class="embed-responsive-item" src="..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Here's how it looks like on the browser:
[image: embedded media on website]

But when I click the print button the print preview shows this:
[image: embbeded media on pdf]

As you can see it seems like the embedded media gets zoomed in even if it looks fine on the browser. I even tried setting the height and width of the iframe manually (e.g. `width="" height=""`)but the media just gets cut off in printing. I also learned that based on the resize of the iframe what gets cut off changes as well. So when I minimize the browser and click the print button, the embedded visuals suddenly fits inside the print preview! I just want my embedded media to fit in the print page and not get cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the bootstrap responsive component what I did was change the code into this:

```
<div id="powerbi-include" style="zoom: 3.55">
    <iframe  id="iframePrint" src="..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

on my print.css I added this block of code:

```
@media print {
    #powerbi-include {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.70, 0.70); 
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.70, 0.70); 
        -o-transform: scale(0.70, 0.70);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.70, 0.70);
        transform: scale(0.70, 0.70); 
        -moz-transform-origin: top left;
        -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
        -o-transform-origin: top left;
        -ms-transform-origin: top left;
        transform-origin: top left;
    }
}
```

The downside is that this takes away the responsiveness of the div towards screen size changes. Nonetheless, it is a temporary solution to my problem about the printing.

Comment: Hey, this solution did not work for me, do u have something better now, maybe?